# Uninstalling old xamarin's projects from visual studio android emulator?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

How to uninstall old applications created by Xamarin for Visual Studio without changing source project files?

[image]

If I choose "OK" application won't deploy on the Visual studio android emulator. How I can do this without reinstall emulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key word in your question is **emulator**. For all practical purposes, the visual studio android emulator behaves like a real android device... and thus, you can uninstall applications the same way as on a real phone.

Ways to Uninstall an app: 
1) Open the "Settings" app. Navigate to the "Apps" sections. Select the app you want uninstalled. Tap "Uninstall". (Should work in all versions). 
2) Depending on the device emulated, you may be able to simply select and drag the app icon to a trashbin.

Reference:
https://www.androidpit.com/how-to-uninstall-an-app